# Better MOCKing?

Tags: c++, googlemock

Question:

Let's say I have a class System which has some Component inside. In order to properly test the System I need to keep a pointer to Component in the System class, and design the Component to have an interface, IComponent, with virtual methods. Then in the test, I can create a mock of IComponent and give it to the System.

But in some situtations I don't want such approach.

There is other technique of using templates and specifying the Component as template parameter, like this:

```
template <class Component>
class System
{
    // ...
    Component _component;
};
```

Then, in my test I can create the System giving it a Mock of Component, like this:

```
System<MockComponent> theSystem;
```

The MockComponent does not necesarrily be inherited from IComponent, in my approach I dont want IComponent, I just want MockComponent to have some needed methods, the same as in Component.

But the problem with this approach is that I want to instruct the MockComponent what to do, give it some expectations and tell what to return. From the test I do not have access to the MockComponent because it lives in the System. If the System had a getter of Component then it would be OK, but sometimes I don't want to have a getter of Component in the System. Then, in the test, I need to create another class, MockSystem, and equip it with the getter of the component (and also make sure that the _component in the original System is in "protected" section).

```
template <Class Component>
MockSystem : public System
{
public:
    Component GetComponent() { return _component; }
};
```

Then, in the test I can:

```
MockSystem<MockComponent> theSystem;
MockComponent mockComponent = theSystem.GetComponent();
EXPECT_CALL(mockComponnent, ...);
```

This approach works fine.

But... I wonder if there is a way to simplify this a bit.

What if I had a mechanism of generating, in compile time, the class of MockSystem, from the class of System? I mean I would like to obtain the class of System with getters for all template parameters.

I know that template metaprogramming can do miracles, but I am not an expert in TPM. I've read some examples and seen Boost::Hana in action, and wonder now if this is doable.

Has anyone of guys here heard of or seen a framework for something like this?
Or is there another approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can define wrapper over your mock class - to allow access to mock:

```
struct ComponentMock
{
    MOCK_METHOD0(foo, int());
};
struct ComponentMockWrapper
{
    static ComponentMock* mock;
    int foo()
    {
        return mock->foo();
    }
};
ComponentMock* ComponentMockWrapper::mock;
```

Then, in your TestSuite:

```
class SystemTestSuite : public testing::Test
{
protected:
     ComponentMock componentMock;
     void SetUp() override
     {
        ComponentMockWrapper::mock = &componentMock;
     }
     System<ComponentMockWrapper> objectUnderTest;
};
```

And test like this:

```
TEST_F(SystemTestSuite1, shallFooComponent)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(componentMock, foo());
    objectUnderTest.foo();
}
```

But be aware  of such problems like - what to do if 2 or more `Component` needed, or how to keep track of lifetime of testable `Component`...

---

Maybe better approach is to sacrifice a little encapsulation in favor of testability - i.e. get protected access to component:

```
template <class Component>
class System
{
protected:
    Component& getComponent(); // for UT only
};
```

And allow public access in UT by promoting this function:

```
template <class Component>
class SystemTestable : public System<Component>
{
public:
    using System<Component>::getComponent;
};

class SystemTestSuite : public testing::Test
{
protected:
     SystemTestable<ComponentMock> objectUnderTest;
};
```